# How to set the query to select array element in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In this document , I need to update  the ready field of only one element of the array
[image]

but I don't know how to set the query , I'm getting error , this is my incomplete code

```
updateUserState = function(req,res){
    var query = {_id: req.body.game_id};
    var update = {$set: { users: { ready: true }}};
    var options = {'new': true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true};
    Game.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,options, function(err,data){
        if(err)res.send(err)
        else res.send(data)
    })
}
```

I neet to  select by the _id that its done and add to select by `users.user` but I don't know how

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Concepts**

- `field.$[].subField` to update **every** subField,
- `field.$[element].subField` to impose a condition on **element**.

**Code**

```
updateUserState = function(req,res){
    var query = {_id: req.body.game_id};
    var update = {$set: { users.$[thisone].ready: true }}};
    var options = {'new': true, 'safe': true, 'upsert': true, 
    arrayFilters:[{ "thisone._id":<idhere> }] } 
    };
    Game.findOneAndUpdate(query,update,options, function(err,data){
        if(err)res.send(err)
        else res.send(data)
    })
}
```